# Infinite loop while printing a graph

Tags: c

I am trying to print all the vertices and their edges in a graph. I have used adjacency list representation for the graph. My code is

```
#define MAX 1000

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *arr[MAX];


void printGraph(int n)
{
    // n is the number of vertex

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("The vertex %d is connected to");

        if(arr[i]->next==NULL)
            printf("no edges");
        else
        {
            struct node *tmp;
            for(tmp=arr[i];tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)
                printf("%d",tmp->data);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Whenever I call the `printGraph` method, my program goes into an infinite loop. Where could be the error ?

---

`I am adding my other methods. Please check them to see if I am properly creating a graph`

---

```
void createEmptyGraph(int n)
{

// n is the number of vertices
int i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    struct node *n;
    n=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    n->data=i;
    n->next=NULL;

    arr[i]=n;
}

printf("\nAn empty graph with %d vertices has been sreated",n);
printf("\nNo edge is connected yet");
}

void addNode(int startVertex,int endVertex)
{

// For directed edges
struct node *n;
n=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n->next=arr[startVertex];
arr[startVertex]->next=n;


printf("\nAn edge between directed from %d to %d has been added",startVertex,endVertex);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `n` isn't ever reached?

Comment: Probably the graph has cycles.

Comment: May be you don't set tmp->next to NULL properly when you create your graph?

Comment: So am I not supposed to print a graph like this ?

Comment: Show us input and output data, then maybe we will be able to find mistake.

Comment: NOTE: follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11549063/905902 . BTW: do the arr[i] entries actually point to something?. Also: `printf("The vertex %d is connected to");` needs an argument ("i" probably) and: add some '\n' to your printf format strings.

Comment: Step through with a debugger - this will SHOW you what is going on

Comment: As @Henrik said, the graph is probably cyclic. You should check in your for loop is `tmp` ever becomes `arr[i]` again, which indicates the list you're looping through is cyclic (maybe `assert()` on it).

Answer (score 0):

may be `tmp!=NULL` never happens ... ?

Answer (score 0):

this could loop forever `for(tmp=arr[i];tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next)` if arr[i] it's inside a cycle: keep a vector of visited to check and break on cycles, something like:

```
node *visited[MAX];
int nVis = 0;
bool cycle = false;
for(tmp=arr[i];tmp!=NULL && !cycle;tmp=tmp->next) {
  for (int j = 0; j < nVis; ++j)
   if (visited[j] == tmp) {
     cycle = true;
     break;
   }
 visited[nVis++] = tmp;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n->next=arr[startVertex];
arr[startVertex]->next=n;
```

this code make tmp!=NULL never happens

maybe like this:

```
n->next=arr[startVertex]->next;
arr[startVertex]->next=n;
```